# Set cardinality, function onto, open unit square maps into real number set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have a question in my homework that I have trouble solving it. I'm not sure if I understand the question actually. I'll attach the question below and hope someone could give me any hints.

**Consider the open interval $(0,1)$, and let $S$ be the set of points in the open unit square; that is, $S = \{ (x,y): 0 < x, y < 1 \}$. Use the fact that every real number has a decimal expansion to produce a $1-1$ function that maps $S$ into $(0,1)$. Discuss whether the formulated function is onto.**

edited: there's a hint in the question **"keep in mind that any terminating decimal expansion such as .235 represents the same real number as .2349999... ."**

I think the "formulated function" is the $f: S \to (0,1)$. I don't know how to use the decimal expansion concept.

Thanks

Comment: Just for future reference, if you put dollar signs around your math, it will render the math.  For example, if I write the text "$\text{ If \$S\$ is a set, and \$(0,1)\$ is the unit interval, then \$f: S \to (0,1)\$ is a function...}$", everyone will see this: "If $S$ is a set, and $(0,1)$ is the unit interval, then $f: S \to (0,1)$ is a function..."

Comment: thanks, I don't know how to type math symbols yet. I'll use the dollar sign in the future. @user46944

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in S$, $x$ has the decimal expansion $0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots$, and $y$ has the decimal expansion $0.e_1e_2e_3\ldots$, we can mesh the expansions to send $\langle x,y\rangle$ to the real number $f(x,y)$ whose decimal expansion is $0.d_1e_1d_2e_2d_3e_3\ldots\;$. However, there are several problems that have to be dealt with.

First, as the hint points out, some real numbers have two decimal expansions: $0.5=0.4999\ldots$, for instance. If we want the function $f$ to be well-defined, we’ll have to specify which expansion to use for such numbers. For simplicity let’s agree to use the one that terminates, padded with zeroes, so that $\frac12$ will be represented by $0.5000\ldots$, not by $0.4999\ldots$. Thus, the point $\left\langle\frac13,\frac12\right\rangle$ is sent by $f$ to the real number whose decimal expansion is $0.35303030\ldots\;$.

You have to do two things. First, you have to prove that this map always produces a real number in $(0,1)$. Then you have to decide whether the function maps $S$ **onto** $(0,1)$ or only **into** $(0,1)$. In other words, is there some $x\in(0,1)$ that is not $f(x,y)$ for any $\langle x,y\rangle\in S$. HINT: Consider the number $\frac1{11}$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the extended problem of the Hilbert hotel? Suppose you have a hotel with infinitely many rooms numbered $R_1\cdots R_\omega$ which are all full. Suppose infinitely (but countably) many new guests arrive and you have to accommodate them all. The problem you have is very similar if you think of a point in $S=(a,b)$ as being the two sets of guests (the ones in the rooms already and the newly arrived ones) and the points in $(0,1)$ as each being a Hilbert hotel.You will ofcourse have to also deal with repeating decimals but you can manage that by just adding another set of guests to your hotel.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the two sequences of decimal expansions of $x$ and $y$. How do you combine them into one sequence injectively?

Comment: for this matter, I think simply a injective function would work. let $f(x)=x$    but I'm still confused, especially after seeing the hints. it's asking if it's onto. Then it is onto because of the hint part in the question, right? But how to write that mathematically?

Comment: oh, I don't have a new question. Sorry for being ambiguous. By saying "hint" in the comment above, I mean the "hint" part given in the question which added to the question above because I didn't mention it in the first place. @hjhjhj57

Comment: @JasonHu I'm talking about the answer. Which, I mistakenly thought was another question posted as an answer.